# Transform XML file to CSV with Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, xml-parsing, transformation

I need to convert my xml file to csv file using Python. The xml is hadly nested and I use the next code:

```
#head = ['order-date', 'original-order-no', 'customer-email', 'quantity']
head = ['order_no', 'order_date', 'name', 'email', 'product_id',  'product_name', 'quantity']
body = []
for i in root.findall('.//customer/customer-email'):
    email = i.text
    body.append({'email': email})
for i in root.findall('./order/original-order-no'):
    order_no = i.text
    body.append({'order_no': order_no})
for i in root.findall('./order/order-date'):
    order_date = i.text
    body.append({'order_date': order_date})
for i in root.findall('.//customer/billing-address/first-name'):
    name = i.text
    body.append({'name': name})
for i in root.findall('.//product-lineitems/product-lineitem/product-id'):
    product_id = i.text
    body.append({'product_id': product_id})
for i in root.findall('.//product-lineitems/product-lineitem/product-name'):
    product_name = i.text
    body.append({'product_name': product_name})
for i in root.findall('.//product-lineitems/product-lineitem/quantity'):
    quantity = i.text
    body.append({'quantity': quantity})
print(body)
```

Then I convert it to DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(body, columns = head)
```

My dataframe looks like this:
[image]

But I need to have it like this:

```
order_no    order_date  name    email              product_id   product_name       quantity
00357011    2021-08-08  Sanchez sanchez@gmail.com   C2CPROS     Bucket Hat Purple     1
00357011    2021-08-08  Sanchez sanchez@gmail.com   CMLOS       Bandana Multi         1
```

Is there any way to reach it?

Please, have attached the xml file:

[image]

Comment: Please show sample of XML for [mcve]. Mockup actual data as needed.

Comment: I have attached an example of xml file.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of sample code or data. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451) for many reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), special-purpose language to transform XML files such as flattening nested documents for easier migration to a two-dimensional data frame. The recently added IO tool, [**`pandas.read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html), using the third-party `lxml` parser supports XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Specifically, below XSLT will parse down to lowest granularity, `<product-lineitem>`, and then pull higher level order and customer details using `ancestor::*` axis. Adjust the second template for other needed information.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/orders">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::product-lineitem"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product-lineitem">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::order/original-order-no"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::order/order-date"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::order/customer/billing-address/first-name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::order/customer/billing-address/last-name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::order/customer/customer-email"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product-id"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="product-name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="quantity"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(requires `lxml` package to be installed)*

```py
import pandas as pd  # v1.3+

order_df = pd.read_xml(
    "Input.xml", 
    names = [
        "order_no", "order_date", "first_name", "last_name", "email",
        "product_id",  "product_name", "quantity"
    ],
    stylesheet="Script.xsl"
)
```